# Confusion between selection and arrangement in probability

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Hi I am a beginner in probability, I have been following Harvard course Stat 110 class taught by Joseph Blitzstein on Youtube.

I am having confusion with following problem.

Scenario 1

Consider there are k distinguishable items and n distinguishable boxes, What are the ways in which you can put these k items in n boxes

Answer: It's pretty straight forward = n^k

**Question**

1) In the answer stated above are we not considering the way items are arranged in each box?

2) What would be the answer if the order in the boxes is considered?

Scenario 2:

Same problem if we are to encode it in a slightly different way, k items represented as k distinguishable dots and n boxes represented as | indistinguishable separators (for n boxes we would be having n-1 separators), like this

...|..||.   - 4 boxes and 6 items

Considering the order among the k items is not important, what are the ways in which we can have this encoded information represented ?

Answer:

There are k+n-1 total objects, the way in which you can arrange them is 
(k+n-1)!/((n-1)! * k!) (considering order of k items do not matter)

**Question**

3) Same problem is in scenario 1 is being represented a bit differently in scenario 2, How are the solutions different ? Though we are arranging in 2nd scenario we are not considering order of k items?

Please help correct my understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) In the answer stated above are we not considering the way items are arranged in each box?

Yes, we are not considering the way the items are arranged within each box.   We are counting ways to assign a distinct box to each distinct ball.

> 2) What would be the answer if the order in the boxes is considered?

The order of the boxes *is* considered.   That is: being distinct, each box has a distinguishable address.

> 3) Same problem is in scenario 1 is being represented a bit differently in scenario 2, How are the solutions different ? Though we are arranging in 2nd scenario we are not considering order of k items?

It is a *different* problem, and it is presented *incorrectly*.

The given "stars and bars" solution counts distinguishable ways to arrange $k$ *indistinguishable* balls and $n-1$ seperators (indistinguishable, but used to demark distinct locations).  $$\dfrac{(k+n-1)!}{k!~(n-1)!}$$